# Can i partition a stream combining with the grouping by functionality?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, grouping

I am grouping and partioning a stream as follows:

```
// Partioning
Map<Boolean, List<Person>> partitioned = persons.stream().
                                          collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(p -> p.getAge() > 20));

// Grouping
Map<String, List<Person>> grouped = persons.stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getCity()));
```

Is there a way i can combine both of these? I tried combining both with using groupingBy inside partioningBy, but did not get the things right. Any suggestion?

The expected result is the partition the persons with those whose name starts with P and group them by age.
Here is the persons list:

```
List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
            new Person("Max", 18),
            new Person("Peter", 23),
            new Person("Pamela", 23),
            new Person("David", 12),
            new Person("Pam", 12));
```

Comment: What would be the expected result?

Comment: These statements are working fine.

Comment: @Tunaki made the edits to see the expectations.

Comment: Look at the downstream collector [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.stream.Collector-).

Comment: @Holger Changed the statements, Sorry typo error from my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following and somhow it worked.

```
Map<Boolean, Map<Object, List<Person>>> rr = persons.stream()
                                            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(p -> p.name.startsWith("P"), 
                                                    Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.age > 20)));
```

The output was as expected

```
rr = {false={false=[Max, David]}, true={false=[Pam], true=[Peter, Pamela]}}
```

But, i am not sure is it the efficient way to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no absolute efficiency. Since the code doesn’t even remotely what you have asked in your question, it’s very inefficient in respect to your original goal. Of course, the pattern behind it is sufficient to solve your original question.

Answer (score 0):

> expected result is the ***partition the persons with those whose name
>   starts with P*** and ***group them by age***

From the question, what seems like is that you don't need to perform a conditional check within `groupingBy` as:

```
Map<Boolean, Map<Integer, List<String>>> rr = persons.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(p -> p.getName().startsWith("P"),
                Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getAge,
                        // just for printing the output below
                        Collectors.mapping(Person::getName, Collectors.toList()))));
```

This would result given your input into:

```
{false={18=[Max], 12=[David]}, true={23=[Peter, Pamela], 12=[Pam]}}
 ^                                    ^
 partitioned (startsWith P)          grouped by(age)
```